# How to prevent anti-aliasing of bitmap font in IE and FF

Tags: css, icons, font-face

I have a basic bitmap font for icons.

It's crisp in Chrome but the font smoothing in IE and FF makes the icons look blurry.

Any suggestion on how to fix the issue?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxiOh.jpg

Font was created with http://fontstruct.com

@font-face was generated by http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator using optimal setting. Also tried expert to remove font hinting with same result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with text rendering in different browsers and operating systems. I believe the default for webkit browsers (Safari and Chrome) is `subpixel-antialiased`. You may try playing around with the [font-smooth](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-font/#font-smooth-prop) css property, though I'm not sure how widely it is supported. Typekit has a bunch of [articles](http://blog.typekit.com/2010/10/21/type-rendering-web-browsers/) on text rendering you might like to take a look at, but if you are looking for an extremely consistent look across multiple browsers, your best option is an image sprite.